# VisiWinNet Loading image from file

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to figure out how to load a picture from a file and can not seem to get it to work. Everywhere I looked online said to use Image.FromFile("File path") The problem I am running into is that whenever I code the Image.FromFile I get a error saying 'FromFile' is not a member of 'System.Drawing.Image'. I am using VisiWinNet software which I believe uses VB.Net 2005. I tried it in visual studios and this worked completely fine. Anyone got any ideas of another way to accomplish this?
My code was simply

```
PictureBox3.Images = Image.FromFile("C:\FY13\Later.jpg")
```

Comment: not following the rules, thanks, no vote...

Answer (score 0):

According to this;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.80).aspx

```
Version Information
.NET Framework
Supported in: 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
```

It's supported since framework 1.0

I've also tried;

```
         PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\t.png")
```

works fine for me...

So ask it to VisiWinNet, don't know what it is, but ask them, in vanilla .net your construction works like a charm...

(you spelled; images vs image)

Comment: In VisiWinNet the property is tagged as images. I am thinking something in VisiWinNet is different or works differently than what I think it is. Thank you for your thoughts though!